# Shows a dropdown element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I'm recreating the Office 2013 ribbon in Html, css and javascript.
This is my first approach so don't judge me on css/html/js code.

Currently the ribbon is working with a dropdown but I have an issue.

The dropdown is showed when you click the corresponding icons, but I don't know how to hide it if I click anywhere in the document.

I can probably come up with a solution, but I'm not too sure that it will be a good approach.
Can someone have a look and given me a good solution to accomplish this?

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/mwCCt/

Here's the code to open it:

```
$("#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon").children().each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("menu")) {

        var element = $(this);

        $('<i class="fa fa-sort-asc arrow"></i>').appendTo($(this).prev());

        // Add a click event to the element that contains a menu.
        $(this).parent().click(function() {
            $(element).toggle();
                        $(element).parent().addClass("active");
        });
    }
});
```

Just click the "New items" button on the ribbon (second one) and then the dropdown menu will open.

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take advantage of the `stopPropagation()` function:

```
$("#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon").children().each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("menu")) {

        var element = $(this);

        $('<i class="fa fa-sort-asc arrow"></i>').appendTo($(this).prev());

        // Add a click event to the element that contains a menu.
        $(this).parent().click(function(e) {
            // Stops click event from bubbling up to $(document)
            e.stopPropagation();

            // Do stuff
            $(element).toggle().parent().addClass("active");
        });
        }
    });

    // Bind click event to document, to hide any .menu elements that are open
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('.menu').hide();
    });
});
```

p/s: You should take advantage of chaining, so I combined the two lines referencing $(element) into a single one :) that is one of the most powerful features of jQuery, so go crazy :D

---

**Update**: OP asked to also detect click events within the menu item itself. This entails storing the toggle state somewhere, which I have chosen to use the `data` object for, and sniffing the toggle state on click before deciding to open/close the menu (and perform other actions, such as adding/removing class from parents):

```
$("#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon").children().each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("menu")) {

        var element = $(this);

        $('<i class="fa fa-sort-asc arrow"></i>').appendTo($(this).prev());

        // Add a click event to the element that contains a menu.
        $(this).parent().click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            // Check toggle state
            if(!$(this).data('state') || $(this).data('state') == 0) {
                // If menu is closed, show it
                $(element).show().parent().addClass('active');

                // Update state
                $(this).data('state', 1);

            } else if ($(this).data('state') == 1) {
                // If menu is already open, close it
                $(element).hide().parent().removeClass('active');

                // Update state
                $(this).data('state', 0);
            }

        });
    }
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $('.menu').each(function() {
        $(this).hide().parent().data('state', 0).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

See *updated* fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/mwCCt/5/

Comment: Almost working. The active class is not removed. How should that be done (in the document click) or is there any other solution? If I know that it's working and I will be a very happy person :-)

Comment: Just change this line: `$('.menu').hide();` to this: `$('.menu').hide().parent().removeClass('active');`

Comment: That's exactely what I tried but it doesn't work and to be honest, I don't have a clue why not? Could you have a quick look?

Comment: It's working for me, please explain. Where are you clicking? If you mean clicking on the menu item itself does not remove the active class, then yes, that is an issue that needs to be addressed. If you  mean clicking elsewhere does not remove the class... that's strange.

Comment: Clicking anywhere in the document does work, but as you mentioned clicking an item in the DropDown doesn't work. Is there a solution for?

Comment: You have to toggle states, to see if the `.menu` has been displayed or not. It's a bit more complicated but entirely doable

Comment: Almost there, sorry to ask those questions, but if the menu is hidden now with a click outside the menu, the state is not updated and therefore, the next time 2 clicks on the dropdown are needed before the item can be showed. I think this is a very little change?

Comment: I've managed to save the state at another place and now it's working.

Comment: Updated answer to also alter state when document is clicked on.

Comment: Great, it's working. I've also updated your fiddle with 2 dropdown elements. Seems that it's working, but when I click on another dropdown the first is not hidden automatticly, but I'm working on it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Tougher than I tought. If you have any idea, please let me know. That way the dropdown is finished and bugs are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add a event listener when you show it that is basically

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    //hide dropdown
});
```

You will want to destroy this event listener after you hide

without being tested... something like this

```
$("#OfficeUI .ribbon .tabs > ul li[role=tab] .contents .group .icongroup .icon").children().each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("menu")) {

        var element = $(this);

        $('<i class="fa fa-sort-asc arrow"></i>').appendTo($(this).prev());

        // Add a click event to the element that contains a menu.
        $(this).parent().click(function() {
            $(element).toggle();
            var dd = $(element).parent();
            dd.addClass("active");
            hideDD = function(){
               dd.removeClass('active');
               $(document).removeEventListener('click',hideDD);
            };
            $(document).addEventListener('click',hideDD);

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I'm not very familiar with jQuery. Would you be so kind to provide me a bit more information. Maybe a little fiddle to show me what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event on the document, check that the target of the click is not the icons, then hide the element as needed

```
jQuery(document).on("click",function(e){
   if( !jQuery(e.target).hasClass("icon") ) {
       //hide ribbon code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the relevant code in the focus-out event of the element